# How to use the method of base class in the subclass of derived class?

Tags: python, oop, super

I need the python to use the method of base class in the below program.
I read lots of documentation, even after that also, I couldn't able to figure it out how super works when the below kind of situation occurs.

```
class Car:
    time = 2
    def __init__(self, color, company,powertrain,velocity):
        self.color = color
        self.company = company
        self.powertrain = powertrain
        self.velocity = velocity

    def speed(self):
        return self.velocity

    def __self__(self):
        return self.powertrain   #just self.powertrain to print it

class Conventional(Car):

    def speed(self):

        return self.velocity *self.time*2

class Electric(Car):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def speed(self):
        return super().velocity * super().time*3

 class Hybrid(Electric,Conventional):

    pass
```

Now I need hybrid object to use the method of Car class, I think I can use composition concept here. But I need to know how super works here. I also know mro to get the order in which python looks for the method. mro.

```
car = Hybrid("blue", "Audi", "hyrid", 50)
car.speed()
```

Any better way to write the above code is most welcomed. 
I think if I get the solution to the above problem using super (), I can understand the complete functionality of super properly.
To see all the possibilities I Used different syntax. Don't mind

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope it will clarifies all your doubts     https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/python-tutorial-understanding-python-mro-class-search-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
super(Electric, Electric).speed(self, velocity)
```

Explanation:
super can take two optional arguments, the superclass (direct superclass) it should use, and class that it should start searching through MRO from.:
MRO: Hybrid -> Electric -> Car -> Conventional -> Car
By passing Electric we make MRO:
Car -> Conventional -> Car
(multiple inheritance is awful)
When we resolve inheritance like this, we also need to pass the current object explicitly (self).
Btw, you should fix your inits, they dont resolve propely, you should always pass down the *args, and let the super resolve arguments for you.

```
class Car:
    time = 2
    def __init__(self, color, company,powertrain,velocity):
        self.color = color
        self.company = company
        self.powertrain = powertrain
        self.velocity = velocity

    def speed(self, velocity):
        return self.velocity

    def __self__(self):
        return self.powertrain   #just self.powertrain to print it

class Conventional(Car):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super().__init__(*args)


    def speed(self):

        return self.velocity *self.time*2

class Electric(Car):

    def __init__(self,*args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def speed(self):
        return super().velocity * super().time*3

class Hybrid(Electric,Conventional):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def speed(self):
        return super(Electric, Electric
                ).speed(self,50)

car = Hybrid("blue", "Audi", "hyrid", 50)
car.speed()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to re-organize your code. If you use self.velocity in Car class speed method you dont need to take second argument velocity because you don`t use this in method, you are using self.velocity which is created in **init**.

And you can use lambda functions to "map" old speed method to variable

Try to create lambda function in Hybrid class

```
self.speed_carclass = lambda speed x=Car: Car.speed(x)
```

and then outside class call it

```
hybrid_speed = <class istance>.speed_carclass()
```

hybrid_speed will be the same value as velocity variable when you created Car